# How to extract country names using Xquery?

Tags: xml, xquery, flwor

**tempdata.xml**

```
<ArticleSet>
<Article>
    <LastName>Chang</LastName>
    <ForeName>K W</ForeName>
    <Affiliation>Department of Surgery, Army General Hospital, Taiwan, Republic of
    China.</Affiliation>
</Article>
<Article>       
    <LastName>Ferree</LastName>
    <ForeName>B A</ForeName>
    <Affiliation>Children's Hospital Medical Center, Cincinnati, Ohio.</Affiliation>        
</Article>
<Article>
    <LastName>Dyck</LastName>
    <ForeName>P</ForeName>
    <Affiliation>Department of Neurosurgery, University of Southern California, Los Angeles.</Affiliation>      
</Article>
<Article>
    <LastName>Lonstein</LastName>
    <ForeName>J E</ForeName>
    <Affiliation>Minnesota Spine Center, Minneapolis 55454-1419.</Affiliation>      
</Article>
</ArticleSet>
```

**Countries.xml**

```
<Countries>
    <Country>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Los Angeles</name>
        <code>ad</code>
    </Country>
    <Country>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Republic of China</name>
        <code>ae</code>
    </Country>
    <Country>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>China</name>
        <code>af</code>
    </Country>
    <Country>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>Ohio</name>
        <code>ag</code>
    </Country>
</Countries>
```

**XQuery Code**

```
declare variable $tokens:="";
declare variable $aff:="";
for $article in doc("tempdata.xml")/ArticleSet/Article
  let $aff:=data($article/Affiliation)
  let $aff:=replace($aff,'[;,.]',',')
  for $tokens in tokenize($aff,',')
    for $countries in doc("countries.xml")/Countries/Country
      return if($countries/name= normalize-space($tokens))
        then <Country>{data($countries/name)}</Country>
```

This XQuery code matches the string in `Affiliation` tag of `tempdata.xml` with the list of countries in  `Countries.xml` file and prints country names. At first the Affiliation string is tokenized and each token is matched against list of available countries.

**Output**

```
<Country>Republic of China</Country>
<Country>Ohio</Country>
<Country>Los Angeles</Country>
```

I want to print an `<Country>-</Country>` tag for the strings in which there is no country found. For example in 4th Affiliation, there is no country so here in this type of situation, I want to insert a hyphen based tag.So my question is where to write else part so that i can get the following output.

**Required Output**

```
<Country>Republic of China</Country>
<Country>Ohio</Country>
<Country>Los Angeles</Country>
<Country>-</Country>
```

Comment: The `if` expression XQuery has an `else` branch anyway (https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-conditionals with `IfExpr    ::=    "if" "(" Expr ")" "then" ExprSingle "else" ExprSingle`) so I wonder why your attempt without `else` works at all and why you haven't used it,

Comment: That looks like BaseX's non-standard [syntax extension](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Extensions#If_Without_Else) which interprets `if($A) then $B` as `if($A) then $B else ()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query potentially returns multiple `<Country>` elements per article, one per matched affiliation. You rely on at most one match existing. You can gather all matches, add `"-"` as a fallback and then take the first candidate of that sequence:

```
for $article in doc("tempdata.xml")/ArticleSet/Article
let $country :=
  for $aff in tokenize($article/Affiliation, '[;,\.]')
  where doc("countries.xml")/Countries/Country/name = normalize-space($aff)
  return normalize-space($aff)
return <Country>{($country, '-')[1]}</Country>
```